# How do I make sure that it is connected() before any method is invoked? My methods are beight called AFTER the GooglePlus authentication

Tags: android, google-play-services

Please see the following LogCat output. In Base.OnStart() I am calling mPlusClient.connect(); Now I am calling various methods in ShowLog.OnStart, but just because the Google is not yet authenticated, it throws error "GoogleApiClient is not connected".

What should I do to change my design, so that it always connects and then only I call the various methods.

```
mainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu called
Base.onConnectionFailed called
onClick called
onActivityResult called
Base: onConnected called. Is Google connected?true
showLog: onCreate
Base: onCreate
showLog: onCreate: is Google connected?false
showLog: onStart
Base: onStart
Base: onStart. Is Google connected?false
**showLog: onStart: is Google connected?false**
showLogsActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu called
Base: onConnected called. Is Google connected? **true**
Base: onStop
showLog: onStop
Base: onStop
```

I am also including the code below (I am removing some code to keep it concise).
Here is the complete code:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:52b6

Thanks
**EDIT 1***
After suggestion I have the code modified as:

```
Class showLog{

@Override
    void onGooglePlayServicesConnected() {
        if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            //background process to get Picasa Photo
            AsynTaskGetPicasaMedia objAsyncTaskGetPicasaMedia = new AsynTaskGetPicasaMedia(getApplicationContext());
            objAsyncTaskGetPicasaMedia.execute();
        }

    }

}
```

Now in class AsynTaskGetPicasaMedia

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


        final String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(BaseActivity.mPlusClient);
}
```

I am still getting the error!

Comment: do what you have to do in `onConnected`

Comment: @tyczj This will not be a good solution, A. I want to separate business logic and Authentication code. B. There are many methods needs to be called. C OnConnected is in the BaseClass, I cant have all the logic into BaseClass,

Comment: if you only want to do stuff when you are connected there is no other way to do guarantee that you are connected other than doing stuff in onConnected. If on connected is the base class then you need to provide a callback that calls up to the top class

Comment: @tyczj Can you please give an example of the callback that you are talking about ?

Comment: @tyczj   
Can you please check my latest updated code, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your base class implements the callbacks to google play services then you create a method in that base class that you call when its connected.

example

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    onGooglePlayServicesConnected();
}

public void onGooglePlayServicesConnected(){

}
```

in your activity that extends this base class just override the method `onGooglePlayServicesConnected()`

```
@Override
public void onGooglePlayServicesConnected() {
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I think I have to believe you looking your your reputation :). I am still having issues. Please see. I have updated my original question.

Comment: what is the issue you are having?

Comment: If you please see my updated code per your suggestion. I am invoking method onGooglePlayServicesConnected() in OnConnected(). In the ShowLog class i have overridden onGooglePlayServicesConnected(). Now from this method, I am calling AsynTaskGetPicasaMedia, and the in the method doInBackground(), I am still getting the error that  "GoogleApiClient is not connected". Thanks,.